# Range for current cell in custom vba function used in formula

Tags: excel, function, vba, formula

I want to write a function `Foo` that can be used in a formula to return the contents of a cell above the cell it is used in.

E.g., if in cell B2, I write `=Foo()` I want to get the contents of B1.

**I know I can write `=B1` directly. Obviously, I'm simplifying the case here.**

So, how does this function look like.

More precisely, I want to (also) be able to use this function from other functions (e.g. a `Bar(factor)` Function that multiplies the cell above, so I can write `=Bar(2)`)

Comment: Why would you want to do this and not, for example, `=Foo(B1)` and `=Bar(B1,2)`? Hard-coding a relative cell reference is like asking for trouble...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works

```vb
Public Function Foo() As Variant
    Foo = Application.ThisCell.Offset(-1, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome on SO and thanks for your answer! It'd be helpful if you [format code snippets accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and provide a terse description of how it works.

Comment: Please note that this function does not work properly: it will not be recalculated when the cell below changes because it references a cell that is not in the function argument list: you need to make it volatile to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

This in general a bad idea because you will have to make the function volatile, with knock-on effects on calculation etc.

```
Public Function Foo() As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Foo = Application.Caller.Offset(-1, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can help with this one as well?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758120/object-required-in-vba-function-for-excel