# 'object required' in vba function for excel?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function RRel(colmn, Optional offst, Optional rng)
    If offst Is Nothing Then Set offst = -1
    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.Caller
    RRel = Intersect(colmn, rng.offset(offst, 0).EntireRow)
End Function
```

When I try to use this as an excel formula, e.g., `=RRel(P:P)` I get an error:

```
Compile error:

object required
```

And the debug point is on the function header

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? From your code it looks like `offst` is a number. Change `If offst Is Nothing Then Set offst = -1` to `If offst = 0 Then offst = -1` But the question still remains... What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need a UDF to do this: why not just do it with Excel formulas?
Anyway if you insist you can try this:

```
Function RRel(colmn As Range, Optional offst As Variant, Optional rng As Variant) As Variant
    If IsMissing(offst) Then offst = -1
    If IsMissing(rng) Then Set rng = Application.Caller.Offset(offst, 0)
    RRel = Intersect(colmn.EntireColumn, rng.EntireRow).Value
End Function
```

Comment: If I use formulas, then if I put in A2 '=B2+A1', and A3 '=B3+A1' (ctrl-D), then if I copy&paste row 2 above row 3, then row 3 becomes row 4 and the formula in A4 (was A3) becomes '=B4+A2', instead of '=B4+A3', which messes the computation

Comment: Still don't understand - should your A3 formula be =B3+A2 ? Anyway your function will do exactly the same as Excel when you insert a row A3=B3+RREL(A:A) is the same as =B3+A2, insert a row and it becomes =B4+A3

Comment: When I insert a row it becomes =B4+A2. this is the problem I'm trying to overcome. i saw i can use formula error checking, but this is easy to forget and i'm not the only one updating the sheet